# en sql server ,como registrar los cambios realizados en una tabla después de un update?

Tags: sql-server-2008

LA pregunta es, como registran los cambios realizados en una tabla?, en especial en una fila, si una fila de 20 columnas y 10 columnas cambian, como obtienen esos cambios ?, que función me da ese dato, he estado investigando que podría utilizar la función **COLUMNS_UPDATED**, que lógica utilizarían ustedes para esto?, alguien puede recomendarme un link o una documentación muy explicita?

Answer (score 1):

Depende del contexto de ejecución. Te expongo una posible solución además de Columns_updated

```
Create table t1 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
go
insert into t1(col1, col2, col3)
values
(1,1,1);
go
```

La sentencia updated al igual que otras, tiene una cláusula output que nos retorna la salida de lo que ha realizado. Pero también tiene acceso a las pseudotablas inserted y deleted. Por tanto:

```
UPDATE t set col2 = 2
output 
    case when inserted.col1 <> deleted.col1 then 'modificado col1' end,
    case when inserted.col2 <> deleted.col2 then 'modificado col2' end,
    case when inserted.col3 <> deleted.col3 then 'modificado col3' end
    
from t1 as t;
```

[image: Resultado 1]

Dado que el valor de deleted.col2 e inserted.col2 no son iguales, se que se ha modificado esa columna.

```
UPDATE t set col1 = 2, col3 = 2
output 
    deleted.col1,
    deleted.col2,
    deleted.col3,
    case when inserted.col1 <> deleted.col1 then 'modificado col1' end,
    case when inserted.col2 <> deleted.col2 then 'modificado col2' end,
    case when inserted.col3 <> deleted.col3 then 'modificado col3' end,
    inserted.col1,
    inserted.col2,
    inserted.col3
    
from t1 as t;
```

Así es que en la salida dispongo de las columnas modificadas en base a una expresión case, y de los valores anteriores y actuales.

[image: result2]

Ahora bien, si vuelvo a ejecutar la misma instrucción:

```
UPDATE t set col1 = 2, col3 = 2
output 
    deleted.col1,
    deleted.col2,
    deleted.col3,
    case when inserted.col1 <> deleted.col1 then 'modificado col1' end,
    case when inserted.col2 <> deleted.col2 then 'modificado col2' end,
    case when inserted.col3 <> deleted.col3 then 'modificado col3' end,
    inserted.col1,
    inserted.col2,
    inserted.col3
    
from t1 as t;
```

[image: Result3]

Es evidente que no hay cambios entre inserted y deleted, y aunque la instrucción update se ha ejecutado y se ha anotado en el log como tal, no ha efectuado ningún cambio.

[Output en update](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/13/clausula-output-en-update/)